# Morgan and a String Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying the problem from the following link:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/morgan-and-a-string/problem

> Jack and Daniel are friends. Both of them like letters, especially
>   upper-case ones.  They are cutting upper-case letters from newspapers,
>   and each one of them has their collection of letters stored in
>   separate stacks.  One beautiful day, Morgan visited Jack and Daniel.
>   He saw their collections. Morgan wondered what is the
>   lexicographically minimal string, made of that two collections. He can
>   take a letter from a collection when it is on the top of the stack. 
>   Also, Morgan wants to use all the letters in the boys' collections.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int flag,choice;
    long n,i,j=0,k=0,x,y;
    char *a,*b;
    a=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100000);
    b=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100000);
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        j=k=0;
        scanf("%s%s",a,b);
        x=strlen(a);
        y=strlen(b);
        while(x<y)a[x++]='Z'+1;
        while(y<x)b[y++]='Z'+1;
        a[x]=b[y]='\0';
        while(j<x && k<y && (a[j]!=('Z'+1) && b[k]!=('Z'+1))){

            if(strcmp(a+j,b+k)<0)printf("%c",a[j++]);
            else printf("%c",b[k++]);

        }
        while(j<x && a[j]!=('Z'+1))printf("%c",a[j++]);
        while(k<y && b[k]!=('Z'+1))printf("%c",b[k++]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I compare both the strings after popping each character. Also, I've taken care of strings of unequal length by appending the shorter string with a character larger than any other alphabet in ASCII. I don't get the correct solution every time.

The following works:

Input:

```
1
c
ca
```

Expected and correct output:

`cac`

The following doesn't:

Input:

```
1
zbc
aaaaz
```

Expected output:

`aaaazbcz`

Actual output:

`aaaazzbc`

What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: Your input buffers are one character short. Also, don't cast `malloc()`.

Comment: That's definitely not the problem in my case. Although, I should have left an extra character as you said, not a single test case string reached that far. I'll take note of your advice on type casting.

Comment: Two notes: 1) don't complain about the downvotes in the question. It isn't productive, and no one is *required* to explain their votes. 2) I think the downvote is there because you didn't clearly explain what the problem is. What were your inputs? What were your outputs? How did they differ from what you expected? What does "can't quite get the solution every time" mean?

Comment: I can't possibly enter an 8000 character input here. The only possible way I can think of is by telling you all to try my code in the site and try to find out what cases don't work and why, yourself. If I could comprehend the huge output myself, I'd not have posted it here in the first place.

Comment: @MayankVerma I think you're overestimating SO user's enthusiasm. If you want to maximize your chances of getting good answers (and minimize downvotes) you need to make it easier to recreate your problem, and not rely on other people visiting external sites to do so. You may have seen [SO's help page on MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but that idea applies to inputs and outputs too. You're right that we don't want an 8000 character test case, but you should be able to craft a shorter one that breaks your code.

Comment: @MayankVerma It's also your responsibility to understand the output and tell us where it diverges from what you expected.

Comment: It took some some to break my code with a shorter case. But when I got the test case short enough to be posted here, I also understood where the problem lied. I've posted the solution now. I'll take your point into consideration next time I post a question.

Comment: @MayankVerma Ah! I think just about everyone who regularly posts on this site has had that happen, which I suppose is a good thing. Reducing the problem and test cases to their minimums for posting a question often reveals the error. If you can edit the question to include your shortened test case that fails your original code and make the question a bit more specific, I'll remove my close vote.

Comment: @skrrgwasme I've edited the question to make it more precise.

Comment: Good edit. I've retracted my close vote. (I also removed the "update" thing you added. Just adding the answer below is good enough. No need to call it out within the question itself. Questions should remain self-contained and as noise-free as possible.)

Answer (score 2):

I got it now. How about the following case?

```
1
zbc
aaaaz
```

As you see after 4 `a`'s we're left with a `z` and `zbc[[` where `[` is `'Z'+1`. Obviously, `z`<`zbc[[` which creates trouble as the `z` of `zbc[[` should be chosen and not the other one. The result would be `aaaazzbc` while it should be `aaaazbcz`.

So, how do we mitigate this problem?

We append a `[` at the end every time we pop a character from an array to ensure the lengths are equal for `strcmp()` to work as intended. Here's the modified code that's accepted. Too bad I gave up and now I can't score points on that.

Here it is for future reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int flag,choice;
    long n,i,j=0,k=0,x,y;
    char *a,*b;
    a= malloc(sizeof(char)*200000);
    b= malloc(sizeof(char)*200000);
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        j=k=0;
        scanf("%s%s",a,b);
        x=strlen(a);
        y=strlen(b);
        while(x<y)a[x++]='Z'+1;
        while(y<x)b[y++]='Z'+1;
        a[x]=b[y]='\0';
        while(j<x && k<y && (a[j]!=('Z'+1) && b[k]!=('Z'+1))){

            if(strcmp(a+j,b+k)<0){printf("%c",a[j++]);a[x++]='Z'+1;a[x]='\0';}
            else {printf("%c",b[k++]);b[y++]='Z'+1;b[y]='\0';}

        }
        while(j<x && a[j]!=('Z'+1))printf("%c",a[j++]);
        while(k<y && b[k]!=('Z'+1))printf("%c",b[k++]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```